# Selecting multiple rows base on attributes in python jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

df2 = df.loc[df['AustralianPort'] == 'Melbourne']

This syntax enables me to select one row, but how can I select multiple.

When I try df2 = df.loc[df['AustralianPort'] == 'Melbourne', 'Sydney', 'Brisbane','Adelaide', 'Perth']

It prompts me with an error.

Any thoughts on how to select multiple rows??

Comment: Use `df2 = df.loc[df['AustralianPort'].isin(['Melbourne', 'Sydney', 'Brisbane','Adelaide', 'Perth'])]`

Comment: thank you jezrael!